# CSS body property not functioning properly

Tags: html, css, properties

This is my HTML:

```
<body>
<br>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="container">
    <div class="controller" id="prev"></div>
    <div id="slider">
    <img src="resources/Slideshow/AvrilAlbum.png" width="583" height="583"  id="transparent">
    <img src="resources/Slideshow/HTNGU.png" width="583" height="583"  id="transparent">
    <img src="resources/Slideshow/LetMeGo.png" width="583" height="583"  id="transparent">
    <img src="resources/Slideshow/OnTour.png" width="583" height="583"  id="transparent">
        <img src="resources/Slideshow/LetMeGoBuyNow.png" width="583" height="583"  id="transparent">
    <div><img src="resources/Slideshow/RockNRoll.png" width="583" height="583"  id="transparent"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="controller" id="next"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<a class="twitter-timeline" data-dnt="true" href="https://twitter.com/AvrilLavigne" data-widget-id="436842073010888705">Tweets by @AvrilLavigne</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
</body>
```

This is my CSS:

```
body {
        background-color: #0B0B0B;
        background-image:url(resources/body.jpg);
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

The body image and color won't apply for some reason. Although I can get past this by putting a `<style></style>` in my HTML, I have multiple pages that use the same CSS, (also won't apply), and I don't want to put it in each HTML page manually.

Comment: Does stackoverflow restrict you from pasting your code here? Please do the needful.. Paste your code here so that users can help you

Comment: Oh sorry, I just saw other questions doing this and it doesn't fit the comments section. So yeah sorry 'bout that.

Comment: How are you including your CSS file?

Comment: <link href="css/layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

Answer (score 0):

Your css:

```
body {
        background-color: #0B0B0B;
        background-image:url(resources/body.jpg);
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

is fine.

Pasting your code into a fiddle demonstrates that it works: http://jsfiddle.net/Wv9Pk/

Your best bet would to ensure that the path to your css file is correct.

Comment: Also, make sure that you don't have anything farther down your CSS that is overwriting your 'body' CSS (for instance a css reset you may have pasted in, or any other css targeting the body).

Comment: The path is correct and there is no other property overwriting the body property.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `background-image:url(resources/body.jpg);` to `background-image:url('resources/body.jpg');`.

All I've done is put `''` around the path to your image - and make sure that the path is correct!

Comment: Path to CSS is fine, I have other properties using the CSS and they work fine. Tried with the ('') and () still nothing...

Comment: #transparent {
 background-color: #0B0B0B;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to say without a link to your site, but I'd double check that you don't have like `background: white` on your #wrapper, #container or other divs higher up in the source order. Also open the dev tools console (ctrl+shift+i in Chrome) and make sure there aren't any 404 errors on your CSS or other resources that could be causing this unexpected behavior.

Comment: I've checked but no other cause in Chrome or any background properties in my #wrapper or #container. Although I have a background-color:#0B0B0B on a #transparent, I can remove the whole #transparent and the body background still won't show.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't upload it, I don't want to replace the former contents of my site yet because the new one isn't finished. I'm re-doing avrillavigne.com if you'd want to know...

Comment: Why does everything have to be so complicated? (That was a little Avril reference for you.) Do other CSS declarations work on the body selector? E.g. Does `body {color: red !important;}` turn all the text red? If you inspect the body tag in Chrome dev tools, does it show the background-image property being applied? Do you have some sort of CSS minification going on? I'm thinking if it works in <style> tags but not in CSS that there's some sort of error in the CSS or something is conflicting with it. Minifiers can mess things up at times. Invalid CSS can too, make sure all selectors are closed.